# Include a different job in a job's build steps in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to make this rather unique build flow and I haven't found a plugin or a way to do it with jenkins yet.

There is one job called "JOB A" which is used by itself and creates a standalone installer.
Then there is "JOB B" which creates another installer but it needs to include everything built in "JOB A" in addition to some other stuff. Now I could just copy JOB A build steps into JOB B, but I want to actually build JOB A and maybe even use those artifacts later as well.

It cannot be a build trigger cause JOB B needs to continue building after JOB A has finished and I cannot use something like flow because that creates JOB C and only sequences other jobs and I would need to go into A and B to get the artifacts.

Bonus points would be if it checked JOB A source code in git for any changes since its last build when building JOB B and decide if it needs to build it again.

I looked at many plugins and I can't seem to find one that would do this.

I hope my explanation was not confusing. Sorry if it was, I could elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, then what you need is:

- Custom (shared) workspace
- **[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)**

For both, `JOB A` and `JOB B`, setup Custom Workspace to the same folder on the server (You can even leave `JOB A` workspace as is, and just point `JOB B` custome workspace to workspace of `JOB A`. I am not at my work computer with Jenkins and can't provide screenshots, so I will borrow **[this great guide for more info on how to setup custom workspace](http://ingorichter.blogspot.ca/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html)**

Then, whenever appropriate, have `JOB A` execute a build step **Trigger/call builds on other projects**, namely `JOB B`. You can even pass it all the same parameters that `JOB A` had. By default, this will not wait for `JOB B` to complete. It will kick off `JOB B`, meanwhile `JOB A` will finish running, and then `JOB B` completes whenever it is done.

If needed, you can check-mark **Block until triggered projects finish their builds**, and then `JOB A` will wait for `JOB B` to finish before continuing.

So, the above will:

- Share workspace, and not do extra checkouts if code didn't change
- Let `JOB A` and `JOB B` exist independently, with it's own artifacts, and each being able to be triggered separately.
- `JOB B` will get everything from `JOB A` through shared workspace and passed parameters.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I got confused while writing the question myself. I meant that the job that triggers another job needs to wait for it to finish so that it could use its artifacts. You said that by default it does not do that, is there an option to actually do it in parametrized trigger plugin?

Comment: OK, i managed to do what I wanted with that plugin, and I didn't even need to create a shared workspace. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I've modified the answer to include the note about blocking build until triggered build completes, for anyone else looking for the same answer